# Limit Tensorflow CPU and Memory usage

Tags: python, memory-management, tensorflow, cpu-usage

I've seen several questions about GPU Memory with Tensorflow but I've installed it on a Pine64 with no GPU support.

That means I'm running it with very limited resources (CPU and RAM only) and Tensorflow seems to want it all, completely freezing my machine.

Is there a way to limit the amount of processing power and memory allocated to Tensorflow? Something similar to bazel's own `--local_resources` flag?

Answer (score 16):

This will create a session that runs one op at a time, and only one thread per op

```
sess = tf.Session(config=
    tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                   intra_op_parallelism_threads=1))
```

Not sure about limiting memory, it seems to be allocated on demand, I've had TensorFlow freeze my machine when my network wanted 100GB of RAM, so my solution was to make networks that need less RAM

Comment: This threw me the exception `TypeError: target must be a string, but got <class 'tensorflow.core.protobuf.config_pb2.ConfigProto'>
Exception AttributeError: "'Session' object has no attribute '_session'" in <bound method Session.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f8411bba0d0>> ignored`, but adding `config` keyword (i.e. `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1, intra_op_parallelism_threads=1))`)fixed the problem.

Comment: I try to use it on TF 2.2.0 and it throws an error: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'. Solved it by sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1, intra_op_parallelism_threads=1)), but it didn't solve my problem: CPU is loaded on 100%

Comment: @AlexIvanov please see my answer

Answer (score 5):

For TensorFlow 2.x this has been answered in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925061/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-cpus-used-by-tensorlfow-keras):

In Tensorflow 2.x, there is no session anymore. Directly use the config API to set the parallelism at the start of the program.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(2)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(2)
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([...
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading

Comment: What about memory usage?