# How can I reduce the number of CPUs used by Tensorlfow/Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the Keras api of Tensorflow 2.0.

When calling `fit` on my Keras model, it uses all availabel CPUs.

I would like to limit the number of used CPUs. However the way it used to work in former versions of Tensorflow cannot be used anymore:

```
tf.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
       intra_op_parallelism_threads=2, inter_op_parallelism_threads=2)))
```

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v2.keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_session'

How could I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Tensorflow 2.0, there is no session anymore. In eager execution, directly use the config API to set the parallelism at the start of the program like this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(2)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(2)
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([...
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading

Answer (score 0):

The second answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690598/can-keras-with-tensorflow-backend-be-forced-to-use-cpu-or-gpu-at-will) could be a solution to limit the number of CPUs used. You may change the code as

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

num_cores = 4

num_CPU = 1
num_GPU = 0

config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=num_cores,
                        inter_op_parallelism_threads=num_cores, 
                        allow_soft_placement=True,
                        device_count = {'CPU' : num_CPU,
                                        'GPU' : num_GPU}
                       )

session = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

Comment: There's no more Session nor ConfigProto in TF 2.0