# How to handle OOM(out of memory) issue when using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-management, onnx, jetson-xavier

I'm trying to convert a pre-trained model to onnx format. I'm using **tf2onnx.convert** for this purpose. Command that I ran:

```
$ python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model models --output tf_model_op9.onnx
```

On executing the command, I get OOM issue and the process is killed like this:

> 2021-06-10 20:45:45.363569: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 984 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Xavier, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 7.2)
>
> 2021-06-10 20:45:46,335 - INFO - Computed 2 values for constant folding
>
> Killed

On checking **/var/log/kern.log** i get:

> Jun 10 21:01:36 dreamvu-desktop kernel: [559821.101983] Out of memory: Kill process 27888 (python3) score 501 or sacrifice child
>
> Jun 10 21:01:36 dreamvu-desktop kernel: [559821.102503] Killed process 27888 (python3) total-vm:18059264kB, anon-rss:3788464kB, file-rss:126752kB, shmem-rss:0kB
>
> Jun 10 21:01:36 dreamvu-desktop kernel: [559822.232634] oom_reaper: reaped process 27888 (python3), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:127808kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Most of the solutions I find are to limit batch_size(already 1), [gpu resources using sessions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25138#issuecomment-559339162)(already tried) or [change number of threads on cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933374/2735044) or [change memory limit(not supported even in tf v2.5)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/set_logical_device_configuration). I think I need to limit the RAM being used.

How do I do that?

> OS : ubuntu 18.04 ||
> Memory : 7.6 GiB

> Graphics : NVIDIA Tegra Xavier (nvgpu)/integrated

> Processor : ARMv8 Processor rev 0 (v8l) × 6

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a swapfile to provide the extra memory you need ? (assuming you have disk to do so )

as root, or with sudo you would need to:

1. dd if=/dev/zero of=/some/path/swapfile bs=1M count=8192
2. mkswap /some/path/swapfile
3. swapon /some/path/swapfile

use the free command to confirm you have the extra memory available as swap

Comment: I'll need to ask for root. Plus, there is already swap area. Guess, I'll increase it.