# Limit number of cores used on server for tensorflow 2 and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, cpu-usage

I try to run a Python script that trains several Neural Networks using TensorFlow and Keras. The problem is that I cannot restrict the number of cores used on the server, even though it works on my local desktop.

The basic structure is that I have defined a function `run_net` that runs the neural net. This function is called with different parameters in parallel using joblib (see below). Additionally, I have tried running the function iteratively with different parameters which didn't solve the problem.

```
Parallel(n_jobs=1, backend="multiprocessing")(
            delayed(run_net)
```

If I run that on my local Windows Desktop, everything works fine. However, if I try to run the same script on our institute's server with 48 cores and check CPU usage using `htop` command, all cores are used. I already tried setting `n_jobs` in joblib Parallel to 1 and it looks like CPU usage goes to 100% once the tensorflow models are trained.

I already searched for different solutions and the main one that I found is the one below. I define that before running the parallel jobs shown above. I also tried placing the code below before every fit or predict method of the model.

```
NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS = 5
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS,
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=2,
    device_count={"CPU": NUM_PARALLEL_EXEC_UNITS},
)
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

At this point, I am quite lost and have no idea how to make Tensorflow and/or Keras use a limited number of cores as the server I am using is shared across the institute.

The server is running linux. However, I don't know which exact distribution/version it is. I am very new to running code on a server.

These are the versions I am using:

```
python == 3.10.8
tensorflow == 2.10.0
keras == 2.10.0
```

If you need any other information, I am happy to provide that.

**Edit 1**

Both the answer suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925061/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-cpus-used-by-tensorlfow-keras) doesn't work as well as using only these commands:

```
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(5)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reduce the number of CPUs used by Tensorlfow/Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925061/how-can-i-reduce-the-number-of-cpus-used-by-tensorlfow-keras)

Comment: Do you use a queueing system like slurm? if not, you should use it and also can limit the number of CPUs/GPUs exposed to the APIs.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy No, I don't use a queueing system. I thought I could simply run the code that works on my Windows Desktop on the server. Also, I am not the admin of the server but simply have access to the resources. Thus, I am not sure if I am allowed/have the rights to use something like slurm.

Comment: @mujjiga No, this didn't work in my case. I added that to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after trying some things, I have found a solution to my problem. With the following code, I can restrict the number of CPUs used:

```
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "5"
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(5)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(5)
```

Note, that I have no idea how many CPUs will be used in the end. I noticed that it isn't five cores being used but more. As I don't really care about the exact number of cores but just that I don't use all cores, I am fine with that solution for now. If anybody knows how to calculate the number of cores used from the information provided above, let me know.