# Memory leak of TF1 model on CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks

I am running a model in production. Unfortunately I only have access to CPUs and use a TensorFlow 1 model.

I am loading my model using `tf.compat.v1` in TF2:

```py
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(session, [tag_constants.SERVING], './model')
```

Unfortunately when running the session (`self.session.run([out], feed_dict={input_data: batch})`), everytime data is incoming, the memory increases. But after the image is process, it lingers and the memory doesn't get released.

I searched, but only found options for GPUs. Is there a way to limit the CPU memory or solve this problem in a different mannner?

Comment: Does this answer your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619385/14290244

Comment: I did add those parameters but in the end I think: `tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()` is what helped